# Cant receive actual error message on client

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asmx

I have asp net project, i tried call .asmx web service from .aspx page via ajax js. When my web.config file is configured to customErrors mode = On, i receive default error message like "There was an error processing the request".. When customErrors mode = Off i receive real correct business error message.
To Be: i need to configure customErrors mode = On to redirect for custom error pages for our users, but at the same time i really need to receive actual error from asmx services..
Help, please!
Thanks

i tried set customErrors mode = RemoteOnly but it doesnt work: on local host everything is ok but on dev env - the same problem

Comment: You can have multiple webconfigs files via PublishProfiles

Comment: If it's an ajax call you'll have to intercept it with middleware or in global.asax

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.